# How To Serialise JSON Request in Swift using below mentioned code?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, alamofire

> Error: Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character

```
func FAQ(token: String){
    let urlString = BaseURL + "faq?token=" + token
    request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments){(json) -> Void in
        if json.result.error != nil{
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(NotifRequestError.FAQ.rawValue, object: json.result.error, userInfo: nil)
            print(json.result.error)
            return
        }

        let responseDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: json.result.value as! NSDictionary)
        print(responseDict)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(NotifRequestSuccess.FAQ.rawValue, object: self, userInfo: ["data": responseDict])
    }
}
```

Comment: Your json isn't valid

Comment: that's the reason I have posted it here, this code is working for other apis but I am facing this issue in few api calls.

Comment: If you know the json is invalid then your title totally inappropriate for what the actual question is about.

Comment: When I googled this error I found an answer pointing toward serialisation of JSON Request and I don't have any idea how to do it so I posted it here.

Can you help?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(urlString)
```

let  newData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: nil) as? NSData
 let  urlStringToPass = NSString(data: newData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Comment: it is throwing exception

Answer (score -1):

Please check Response in Postman. json response is proper format or not
Bcoz if json is not in proper format .allowfragment will not work.
JSON strings must be enclosed in quotation marks: (see http://www.json.org for the details):
Try to Nsjsonreadingoption from allow fragment to mutablecontainer